# WS API Gateway Websockets HTTP Integration — Target URL rewrite from request body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to dynamically change the integration request URL (http integration point) based on a value inside the body of the message

Lets say the message looks like this:
`{"action": "something", "objectId": "2345werty"}`

I would like my URL to be dependent of the `$.objectId` field from the request.

I have tried stuff like

```
https://${stageVariables.baseUrl}/resource/${request.body.objectId}
https://${stageVariables.baseUrl}/resource/$request.body.objectId
https://${stageVariables.baseUrl}/resource/${input.body.objectId}
https://${stageVariables.baseUrl}/resource/${method.request.body.objectId}
```

The stage variable works fine, but obtaining

I know this is supposed to be somehow possible with HTTP api gateway, but I haven't found a way to do it with the Websockets API Gateway.